# C++ equivalent of new Random(seed) in C#

Tags: c#, c++, random

When we are using a random number generator in C#, we can define a variable like

```
private Random _rndGenerator;
```

in a class and then call

```
_rndGenerator = new Random(seed);
```

correctly in the constructor of the class.

My question is:

What is a C++ equivalent of such a definition (i.e. an RNG in a class). I think it is not a correct approach to use

```
srand((unsigned int)seed);
```

right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

C++11 has much more powerful random-number generation facilities. Here's an example:

```
#include <random>
#include <functional>

std::size_t get_seed(); // whatever is the preferred way of obtaining a seed

typedef std::mt19937 engine_type; // a Mersenne twister engine
std::uniform_int_distribution<engine_type::result_type> udist(0, 200);

engine_type engine;

int main()
{
  // seed rng first:
  engine_type::result_type const seedval = get_seed();
  engine.seed(seedval);

  // bind the engine and the distribution
  auto rng = std::bind(udist, engine);

  // generate a random number
  auto random_number = rng();

  return random_number;
}
```

There are many ways to obtain seeds. `<random>` provides potential access to some hardware entropy with the `std::random_device` class, which you can use to seed your PRNGs.

```
std::size_t get_seed() {
    std::random_device entropy;
    return entropy();
}
```

Comment: And if you're not using a C++11 toolset, there's [Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/libs/random/), which the C++11 random library was loosely based on. In any case, _please_, don't use `rand`.

Comment: `rng_type::result_type` should probably be `engine_type::result_type`

Comment: @MSalters oops, forgot to fix that one. Thanks.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - Would you clarify if `get_seed()` is a dummy function in your code example above, or if this is a member of the standard library?  As far as I can see, `std::time(0)` is the way to go to produce a seed.

Comment: @Dan it's just a placeholder for whatever the preferred method of obtaining a seed is. I added in my preferred way of getting seeds.

Comment: Note: this `get_seed()` function does not work in MinGW ([thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880654/why-do-i-get-same-sequence-for-everyrun-with-stdrandom-device-with-mingw-gcc4))

Answer (score 1):

C++ has a built-in global random number generator. If you want to seed it, then `srand((unsigned int)seed)` is the way to go. This isn't quite the same thing as the C# code that you showed, though. When you write:

```
Random _rndGenerator = new Random(seed);
```

You get a separate random number generator instance. So you can have multiple random number generators in your program. To my knowledge, the C++ library doesn't have such a construct, although it appears that C++ 11 does.

In short, `srand((unsigned int)seed)` is correct if you're using older versions of C++, or if you just want one RNG in your program. If you need multiple RNGs, then use C++ 11, or roll your own.