# Why is the sequence produced by this random number generator always the same?

Tags: c++, random, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I always get the same sequence of random numbers with rand()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108780/why-do-i-always-get-the-same-sequence-of-random-numbers-with-rand)

I tried to implement the following generator class for random integers from a given range:

```
class RandomInteger {

protected:

    std::default_random_engine randomEngine;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribution;

public:

    RandomInteger(int64_t lower, int64_t upper);

    virtual ~RandomInteger();

    virtual int64_t generate();
};


RandomInteger::RandomInteger(int64_t lower, int64_t upper) : distribution(lower, upper) {

}

RandomInteger::~RandomInteger() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

int64_t RandomInteger::generate() {
    int64_t i = this->distribution(this->randomEngine);
    return i;
}
```

It produces integers in the range, BUT the sequence of values it produces is the same each time - not very random. Why?

Comment: Can you also post the code where you set the seed?

Comment: @honk I'm guessing there isn't any, which would be the problem.

Comment: `// TODO Auto-generated destructor stub` Whatever is auto-generating that for you is doing you quite a disservice...

Comment: @ildjarn This is Eclipse CDT. Why exactly is it a disservice?

Comment: Because having a user-declared destructor changes the triviality of your type. Never declare special members when the compiler-generated implementation will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in general a pseudo-random generator takes a seed.

if you never change the seed, you get always the same pseudo-random output/sequence.

edit: I insist on the word **pseudo-random** (somtimes *pseudo-chaos*) instead of the abusivily used `random`

edit2: there should be the c++11 solution to you problem [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389989/c-equivalent-of-new-randomseed-in-c-sharp) (look at @R. Martinho Fernandes 's answer)

Comment: Thanks for the only constructive comment. The "exact duplicate" does not give a C++11 solution.

Comment: There are interesting links on the quoted question however: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108780/why-do-i-always-get-the-same-sequence-of-random-numbers-with-rand

Comment: And maybe the c++11 solution to your question on this one I have added in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389989/c-equivalent-of-new-randomseed-in-c-sharp

Comment: @cls, the answer stays the same: *you need to seed it*. The question and the answer are essentially the same here and that C question.

Comment: @Griwses but we should admit that the c++11 solution is really less straigth-forward...

Comment: You might replace 'psuedo-random' with 'chaotic' but replacing 'random' with 'psuedo-chaotic' doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @StephaneRolland I also liked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217791/random-numbers-in-c0x?rq=1, but I agree with Griwes that OP just didn't think of the seed.

Comment: @honk thx for this other link.

Comment: The word "pseudo-random" was coined specifically to apply to programmatic random number generators. I don't know why you feel a need to coin another one.

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm fine with **pseudo-random** ;-) Just that when I was learning to generate such sequences, the documents and books I read were using the word pseudo-chaotic, so it's the one that I still use... the important to keep in mind is the word **pseudo** :-)

Comment: I edit since you're not the only one to find that word strange.

Comment: "Pseudo-chaotic" returns 4,890 results from Google while "pseudo-random" returns 1,980,000. I honestly had never heard of it before, thanks for introducing me to something new.

Comment: "pseudochaotique" returns 17000 from Google. I most probably have this bias because what I read was in french. It was with Iannis Xenakis about his Stochastic Synthesis, and with french books about Chaos Theory... As a consequence, in english it's probably more correct to say *pseudo-random*. ;-). I re-edit :-)